# Bootstrap 4.3: Column expansion beyond 1200 (xl) screen width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

As I pass the 1200 (xl) break-point in bootstrap, the right hand side column starts to expand faster, and the text in it is now slightly too far from the right edge of container fluid:

[Bootstrap, too much space to the right past 1200](https://ibb.co/Jv4fFDb)

I tried adding the flex utility mr-auto to push the column in the screenshot all the way to the right. But then it stays glued there and I so end up having to set a margin to push it back to the left some.

Desired result: I want the column to continue to slide over to the right as it does before I hit Bootstraps final break-point of 1200; slightly increasing the empty space to the right.

As of now, once I'm past 1200, the space grows much too rapidly; it goes from a gradual increase of space to rocket expansion. Do I need to start thinking of adding more breakpoints or is there another way?

```
   <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row about col-centered">

      <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 mt-md-5">
        <p id="back" class="font-header identity-vw back-nav">---NAV HOLDER</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-5">
        <p class="font-header">.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8 col-xl-7 mt-5">
        <p class="font-header font-size-lg-header">I'M THOMAS<br>THORSTENSSON.</p>
        <p class="font-header font-size-lg-header">I ❤ TO CODE<br>VISUAL STUFF.</p>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-5">
        <p class="font-header">.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-auto mt-6">
        <p class="p-w font-size-para">
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit
          voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam
          rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis
          et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
          Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur
        </p>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I been testing with custom breakpoints by adding a col-xxl and it works much better now. This in my SCSS:

```
$grid-breakpoints: map-merge(
  $grid-breakpoints,
  (
    xxl: 1600px,
    xxxl: 1800px
  )
);
```

Still, I wonder if there is not a better way by using some of those shiny flex utils.